# Closed form expression for power of binomial expression with radical

Tags: nt.number-theory, binomial-coefficients

When performing binomial expansion of $(a+b\sqrt c)^n$ I get $x+y\sqrt c$ where

- $x$ is $\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} \binom{n}{2k} a^{n-2k} b^{2k} c^k$
- $y$ is $\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor (n-1)/2\rfloor} \binom{n}{2k+1} a^{n-2k-1} b^{2k+1} c^k$

Is there a closed end expression for $x$ and $y$? In other words, is there anything that makes summing even/odd binomial coefficients easier?

Answer (score 1):

Yes:
$$x=\frac{\left(a+b \sqrt{c}\right)^n+\left(a-b \sqrt{c}\right)^n}{2}$$
and
$$y=\frac{\left(a+b \sqrt{c}\right)^n-\left(a-b \sqrt{c}\right)^n}{2 \sqrt{c}}.$$

In particular, letting $a=b=c=1$, you attain your stated goal of making "summing even/odd binomial coefficients easier":
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} \binom{n}{2k}
=\sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor (n-1)/2\rfloor} \binom{n}{2k+1}=2^n/2.$$

Comment: Not very helpful. That still includes same expression with radicals.

Comment: What then did you mean, exactly, by "a closed end expression"? What do you want to do with such expressions? The only goal that you clearly stated -- to "make[] summing even/odd binomial coefficients easier" -- is now attained.

Comment: I'd like to be able to quickly calculate expressions like $(3+2\sqrt 5)^{1000}$. Right now I'm using exponentiation by squaring. I was hoping that there's a more efficient way to do the calculation.

Comment: @Eugene : Well, "to quickly calculate expressions like $(3+2\sqrt 5)^{1000}$" is not at all what is actually asked in your post: "a closed end expression for $x$ and $y$" and "anything that makes summing even/odd binomial coefficients easier". So, who do you think should assume the responsibility for the incorrectly stated question? Also, Mathematica computes $x$ and $y$ for $(3+2\sqrt 5)^{1000}$ in about 0.0003 sec. I am sure there are free-license programs that can do similarly. So, how can that be a problem?

Comment: Sorry if I stated the question in a confusing way. Using straightforward exponentiation by squaring algorithm allows me to calculate that value as fast as Mathematica or even faster. I was wondering if there exists an even faster way to do this using some closed end expression.

Comment: @Eugene  If $a,b,c$ are integers, then $x,y$ are integers too. One approach is to evaluate Iosif's expressions to sufficient precision then round to integer. It would be interesting to compare this to your method.

Comment: Maple did $(3+2\sqrt5)^{100000}$ in 0.47 sec by direct expansion and 0.17 sec by 87350-digit real arithmetic. Got the same answer. It would take some model of multiprecision arithmetic to say which is asymptotically faster. For one millionth power, direct expansion has moved ahead: 2.2 sec vs 8.1 sec.

Comment: @Eugene : I think one cannot substantially improve on the speed of the doubling method. E.g., for $n\in\{10^6,10^7\}$, Mathematica computes $7^n$ only about $15$ times as fast as the integers $A$ and $B$ in $A+B\sqrt5=(3+2\sqrt5)^n$ by a doubling method. Here one has to take into account that (i) to multiply $x+y\sqrt5$ and $u+v\sqrt5$ for integers $x,y,u,v$ one needs $4$ multiplications and (ii) Mathematica probably uses built-in (hence faster) basic routines to compute $7^n$.

Comment: @Eugene : But, again, your question, **as stated**, had nothing to do with the speed of calculations. In fact, your stated question was fully answered.

Answer (score 0):

If the point is a formula that does not include radicals, you may write
$$\begin{bmatrix}x \\[0.3em]y \end{bmatrix}:=\begin{bmatrix}a & bc           \\[0.3em]b&a\end{bmatrix}^n\begin{bmatrix}1\\[0.3em]0\end{bmatrix} . $$